# How can I download MacTeX when every time I download it the download fails between 100 and 300 megs out of 1.5 gigs?

Tags: macos, mac, download, latex, mactex

I've somehow managed to download this onto a computer over a year ago but now when I try to do it, every mirror I try (all over the world; I'm in US but tried US mirror first obviously) eventually stops transmitting data around 100 to 300 megs through the download. My ISP blocks torrenting so that's not an option. Is there anyway to get this darn file?

Comment: Do you really need the complete package? You could try if BasicTeX is enough for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded MacTex last week from the link on http://tug.org/mactex/ and it worked really well.  If your download stops and you're using Safari, you can restart the download by double-clicking the **.download** file in Finder after pausing the download or after restarting Safari.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have run into an anti-download measure of your ISP.

I would suggest contacting the ISP's Support and asking for a solution.
Otherwise, download elsewhere using another ISP.

You can also try a download manager that supports resume.

Comment: I have run into this before as well and think @harrymc might be right.  Is it possible for you to try another internet connection to rule in/out the ISP?

Answer (score 0):

As I know if u try torrenting you don't need open port.
Of course with this your download is faster but it's unnecessary.
I think that it can be fault of your Wlan router or ISPs routers causing periodic connection losts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with various browsers. The download would always stop at the same point (9.68MB). However, in Safari you can suspend and then resume the download by clicking in the download progress meter pane. That did the trick for me.